# What is "this" in immediately-invoking functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I guess `this` in immediately-invoking functions always refers to the global/window object in javascript, i.e. the result should be `true` in both nodejs and browser shown below. But this is not the case, I got a `false` in nodejs, why? The code is completely the same.

## main.js

```
var global = this;
(function () {
    console.log(global === this); // false
})();
```

## index.html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var global = this;
      (function () {
          console.log(global === this); // true
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log(this)`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Here's a more direct link. Basically the behavior you're seeing in the browser is deprecated and does not work in strict mode. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript

Comment: If this is a topic you want to know more about, I found this extremely helpful myself https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md